# Resolving distribution list in Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am trying to create an email using VBA which pulls its recipients from a Public Folder with Distribution list.

I have the below code which works except it does not resolve the list, the recipient remains as a string.

```
Sub Email()

Dim list As Outlook.DistListItem
Dim oAPP                       As Object
Dim oItem                      As Object
Const olMailItem               As Long = 0

Set list = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Folders.Item("Planning Weekly Distribution List").Items.Item("Test")

Set oAPP = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oItem = oAPP.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With oItem
     .Display
End With

With oItem
    .BCC = list
    .Subject = "hey"
    .HTMLBody = Body & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
    .Display
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `ResolveAll` method to resolve the recipients of your `MailItem`. Exlained in MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867165.aspx).

Comment: How do I change the DistListItem into a recipient object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was "Planning Weekly Distribution List" folder added as the Outlook address book (right click on the folder, Properties, Outlook Address Book)? If yes, just set the BCC property to "test" - Outlook will resolve the name (assuming it is unambiguous).

If not, you will need to add the DL members as recipients one at a time.

To make sure the folder is used by the Outlook Address Book, set the `MAPIFolder.ShowAsOutlookAB` property.

Comment: The folder was not added to the Outlook Address Book. Is there a way to add it to my local address book?

Comment: I have set that for the "Planning Weekly Distribution List" folder and it still does not resolve the name. I have tried with another contact group name rather than "Test" too.

Comment: Can you see that folder as a container in the Address Book (hit Ctrl + Shift + B)?

Comment: No it does not appear in there at all. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: There appears to be a slight delay in it adding it. Its on after 30 seconds waiting. Thanks!